# Hide Login Page from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add logic in the code to hide the login page if user is already logged in.

```
if (loggedin)
{
    Push to MainViewController
}
else
{
    Show LoginViewController
}
```

I know you can do this in `AppDelegate`, but I am hoping to add this logic in the `LoginViewController`. 
Currently, my logic in the `ViewController` shows the login page for a second then push to the main page. Are there any ways to not see the login page completely?

Comment: Show the real code. What you've posted here is not Objective-C.

Comment: instantinate from storyboad with identifier and present returned viewcontroller

Comment: it isn't possible for writing logic in `LoginViewController`  bcoz if you do like that login page shows for a second like the flash. You can achieve it by write logic in `AppDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if it exactly matches your needs but in one app i do the opposite:
i check in a viewController (the main page) if the user is logged and if it's not i show up the login page like this in the viewDidLoad method:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showFirstTimeLogin) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

I put it in the viewDidLoad so you don't see the "home view controller".
I hope it can help!

Answer (score 1):

You Can check this in App Delegate

In application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([defaults objectForKey:@"email"]!=nil&&[defaults objectForKey:@"password"]!=nil)
{
 viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RevealVC"];
}

else
{
 viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
}

self.window.rootViewController=viewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try to add this logic in viewdidload even before calling its super it may work but i can't make sure of that.
2. you can try a better trick by adding black view controller that you handle this logic at if he is logged in go to the main screen if not show the login screen and while checking that the use will have a black screen thinking the app is loading it will be there for second

and also having this logic is App delegate is not good behaviour from software design point of view

hope this answer will help good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do...instead of starting the user on a login or logged in page, I start them on what I always name a "RouterViewController", I run through the logic needed to figure out where the user should be "routed" and use this librar: https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView to display a nice little animation so that to the user its actually a smooth process.